# Confusion with Unions in C

Tags: c

Simple question about this piece of code:

```
union MyUnion
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

union MyUnion x, y;
x.a = 5;
y.b = 2;
y.a = 3;
x.b = 1;

int c = (x.a - y.b) + (y.a - x.b);
```

Can someone explain why the value of `c` is 0 here ?

Comment: It is Undefined Behaviour to read from any other union field than the last one written to! After `y.a = 3;` you cannot access `y.b` under penalty of demons flying out of your nose.

Comment: @pmg: `under penalty of demons flying out of your nose` - so, no effect, really, then? (mandatory **[link](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=groups2&passive=1209600&continue=http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c/msg/dfe1ef367547684b&followup=http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c/msg/dfe1ef367547684b)**)

Comment: @sehe: that was only an example of UB. Other examples include your program segfaulting, or doing what you expect when the client isn't looking, or a myriad other things

Comment: @pmg: Huh. Someone quoting flying demons, _yet_ doesn't detect irony in my comment (did you see I linked to the 1992 source of the nasal demon?). Anyway, I have demons flying in through my ears all the time too :)

Comment: @pmg: are you sure that it's UB in C? I usually avoid type-punning through unions anyway, but 6.5.2.3 gives rules when it's OK. As does the mysterious footnote 82, which appears to assert something not directly implied elsewhere. Unless `a` and `b` have different addresses, this is a legal type pun since the types are the same. I'm not sure whether it's legal for `a` and `b` to have different addresses, if so then it's unspecified whether they do, but could be ruled out for example by asserting `sizeof(MyUnion) == sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @Steve: apparently that's one change from C89 (3.3.2.3) I didn't take that into account. It's not UB in C99 --- so **it's not UB in C**. Thanks.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I agree that 6.5.2.3 §5 points into that direction. But literally read it is only about `struct`s  in `union`s which we do not have here. And I fail to see what footnote 82 has to do with the issue.

Comment: @undur_gongor: Provided that `a` and `b` have the same address, footnote 82 says that if you write `a` and then read `b`, the bytes of `a` are reinterpreted as an `int`. Since `a` is an `int` in the first place, this is legal with the obvious result.

Comment: That's footnote 82 in TC3 -- undur_gongor checked and it looks as if it was added somewhere between the original C99 and there. So this is a slightly fragile thing to rely on unless someone finds another reference. Footnotes are informative rather than normative, but they are supposed to be *true*. Whether every implementer of C99 has managed to produce the behavior described in a footnote in a corrigendum is another matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only access the last-written field of a union. This code violates that, and thus invokes undefined behavior.

In essence, since both MyUnion.x and MyUnion.y share the same memory, you can probably replace the code with:

```
int x, y;
x = 5;
y = 2;
y = 3;
x = 1;
int c = (x - y) + (y - x);
```

This simplifies down to `c = (1 - 3) + (3 - 1)`, which is `-2 + 2` or `0`.

Note that this is simply based on the observation that this is how compilers typically seem to implement unions, and it explains the observed behavior. It's *still* undefined though, and you should be careful with code like this.

Comment: "You can only access the last-written field of a union" - that's not always true, there are conditions when it is legal to access other members of a union. I think that either this is one of them, or else it's easy enough to test certain implementation properties to ensure that it's one of them. See my comment on the question.

Answer (score 5):

Because (1 - 3) + (3 - 1) = 0

There is only one 'value' in the union, they both use the same memory location, so the last assignment is what the value is.

Comment: Seems to be some rather odd up/down voting going on here

Comment: If you count good answers getting upvoted and bad ones getting downvoted, then yes.

Comment: No, I meant pretty much identical answers being given different votes.  True, I should have mentioned that under the standard this is undefined behaviour for completeness, but mine and the other -ve answers clearly answered the actual ops question.  I'd expect mine and others to not attract votes either way in favour of the more complete answers

Comment: Actually, I'm not convinced it is undefined behaviour, both members are of the same type and as unions are defined as a type consisting of a sequence of members whose storage overlap without unnammed padding at the start, and the bit sequence is based on type.  Different types would be undefined.  A bit of a corner case here I think.

Answer (score 5):

This is undefined behaviour. If you've last written to `x.a`, you're not allowed to read `x.b` and vice versa.

In practical terms, you can rearrange your expression like so:

```
int c = (x.a - x.b) + (y.a - y.b);
```

Since in practice `x.a` and `x.b` share the same memory location (and so do `y.a` and `y.b`), both operands to `+` are always zero.

Answer (score 3):

Both x and y are storing one value, which is the last assigned value, so x holds 1 and y holds 3 (the value is held in both the "a" and "b" members because the storage for them "overlaps" (this is what a union is).

So the equation is `(1 - 3) + (3 - 1) = 0`

And yes, as the other folks have commented, the behavior is undefined (depending on your compiler you might get different answers), but this is **why** you are getting the value 0.

Comment: How do you know that's the reason? He didn't even specify what compiler or system he's using? I'll agree that **most probably** this indeed is the reason, but you can't be sure.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it seems like a reasonable assumption based on his code, and the fact that most compilers I have worked with behave this way.

Comment: @Luchian: Can you name one compiler that doesn't do it this way?

Comment: This is getting completely unproductive.

Answer (score 3):

int c = (1 - 3) + (3 - 1);

When using union, you create space in memory for only one variable, thus replacing its value by last used call.

Comment: It's basically the same what the upvoted users wrote. Now, getting reputation over 125 is really a struggle -.-.

Comment: No, the upvoted answers specified that it's undefined behavior.

Comment: "Unions allow one same portion of memory to be accessed as different data types", by cplusplus.com; so how it can be undefined, if there are two variables of the same type in union?